# Using Python to open a file with a default application, then print once the file opens?

Tags: python, printing

I can open a file in python using it's default application, but is there a way to then print the file once it's open?

**Update:**

I'm literally trying to print a hard copy of the file from the application it was opened in. Not printing the contents of a file such as a .txt file. Sort of like opening a JPEG in MS Paint, then telling MS Paint to print a hard copy.

Is this even possible?

I'm using the Windows OS. Here's how I'm opening the file: 
    os.startfile (r"D:\layout_dev5.mxd") 
where MXD files are opened by an application called "ArcMap"

Comment: *I can open a file in python using it's default application* - It'd be useful to know how you're doing that... Short of somehow automating an application, or using specific command line arguments, you could if you're on Windows look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile and look at passing `print` as the operation to that...

Comment: I think I might of used the term "print" incorrectly.  I'm literally trying to print a hard copy of the file from the application it was opened in.  Not printing the contents of a file such as a .txt file.  Sort of like opening a JPEG in MS Paint, then telling MS Paint to print a hard copy.  Is this even possible?

Comment: I've put your comment into your question to clarify... you may wish to [edit] your question to include your operating system and other details about your environment - including how you've managed to open the application to start with.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to print file content to stdout, you could try something like this:

```
print open("filename.txt").read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename) as fileobj : print fileobj.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best you'll get is "that's not simple but it might work if you have an application set up correctly."

Here is an [example of a script telling notepad to print a document](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9846).

And here is a [discussion of sending PDF's to the printer](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/151242-How-to-send-a-PDF-to-a-printer).

It does sound like you might be able to work with the [ArcMap API's](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#) to get some of what you want too, but I didn't see anything obvious.

And if you can get it output to an image, there are a few different options from there (Photoshop has limited scripting, as does Gimp).

Sorry this isn't a more verbose answer, but I hope it gives you some options.